# pixi js: drag and drop circle

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, pixi.js

I started to create simple js game using [pixijs](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjhsKCtgpbMAhWjQJoKHdUhA-0QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pixijs.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFczp7PxTX24cVaRoVCbzouLzs4ag&sig2=uSPDkzzMjiJVKLFmLZUAnw&bvm=bv.119745492,d.bGs). I need drag'n'drop functionality for Graphics circle but can't find info for this. I see only [this example](http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=demos&f=dragging.js&title=Dragging) with sprites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drag + drop works the same way for both graphics and sprites.

```
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600, { antialias: true });
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

var stage = new PIXI.Container();    
stage.interactive = true;

var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.interactive = true;
graphics.lineStyle(0);
graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF0B, 0.5);
graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 60);
graphics.endFill();
graphics.x = 100;
graphics.y = 100;
stage.addChild(graphics);    

// setup events
graphics
    .on('mousedown', onDragStart)
    .on('touchstart', onDragStart)
    .on('mouseup', onDragEnd)
    .on('mouseupoutside', onDragEnd)
    .on('touchend', onDragEnd)
    .on('touchendoutside', onDragEnd)
    .on('mousemove', onDragMove)
    .on('touchmove', onDragMove);

function onDragStart(event)
{
    // store a reference to the data
    // the reason for this is because of multitouch
    // we want to track the movement of this particular touch
    this.data = event.data;
    this.alpha = 0.5;
    this.dragging = true;
}

function onDragEnd()
{
    this.alpha = 1;

    this.dragging = false;

    // set the interaction data to null
    this.data = null;
}

function onDragMove()
{
    if (this.dragging)
    {
        var newPosition = this.data.getLocalPosition(this.parent);
        this.position.x = newPosition.x;
        this.position.y = newPosition.y;
    }
}

// run the render loop
animate();

function animate() {

    renderer.render(stage);
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented very similar approach. About drop zone: if I want to know when one circle is above another circle. It looks like I need to use contains method of Circle class. Right?

Comment: Why didn't you link your source? http://scottmcdonnell.github.io/pixi-examples/index.html?s=demos&f=dragging.js&title=Dragging

Answer (score 1):

You also need to give `hitArea` for that circle to be able to attach mouse events to it. [Read This Answer by GoodBoyDigital](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/821).

Comment: This is better as a comment.